# php code send a value without showing asking for type definition

Tags: html, forms

if I want to send some value and I do not want to show it on the php screen.
How do i set up for the type for this case??
is it possible to conceal it?

```
<input type='sometype???' name='eid' value = $myrow[eid] />
```

which type should I put to conceal from the screen but it will pass to next php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *really* basic question that you could've solved just by Googling, but here you go:

```
<input type='hidden' name='eid' value='$myrow[eid]'>
```